# How to select an item programmatically in vega?

Tags: vega

The following works, but it doesn't seem right **[(see live demo)](http://livecoding.io/5516392)**:

```
vg.parse.spec(spec, function(chart) {

  var view = chart({
    el: "#graph"
  });

  view.update();

  view.update({
    props: "hover",
    items: view._model._scene.items[0].items[0].items[1] // <- ugly and brittle!
  });

});
```

What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for "vega"?

Comment: See https://github.com/trifacta/vega

Comment: why is this tagged d3? I don't know vega, but looking at the generated elements in your example, it appears to be using a canvas tag.

Comment: Vega does build on top of d3. Besides, in areas where Vega is still lacking, perhaps like this question, you fall back on d3 i assume.

Answer (score 1):

Vega is making good progress and this is one of the features they've talked about in their forum.  However, right now, what you're doing is the only way to get to a scene item.

For proof, see advice from jheer (main author of vega): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vega-js/r4aUahV-RwI (last post there shows an example of traversing the scene the same way you do).

One small difference is you can use `view.model().scene()` instead of `view._model._scene`.  But right now those do the same thing, it's just you don't have to use variables that are actively telling you not to use them :)